# Azure CDN WebApp 404

Tags: asp.net, azure, cdn, azure-cdn

I have followed all the docs on how to set up a CDN for my Azure website but I am still getting a 404 when trying to browse to a file on the cdn eg.

```
https://<custom domain name>.azureedge.net/Content/css/bootatrap.css
```

Browsing to the original website works fine

```
https://<custom domain name>.com/Content/css/bootatrap.css
```

My website is on a custom domain (hosted on Azure) and I have set up as follows
origin type: Web App
origin hostname : .com
origin host header:  .com
origin path:

the origin hostname I actually select from the dropdown
After setting up, I noticed that when I go back into the configuration the origin type is changed to "Custon Origin". Not sure why this happens. Even If I update it back to WebApp, save, exit and re-enter configuration the origin type is set back to "Custom Origin"

I have also tried it with leaving the origin host header blank but it made no difference.

Everything else looks perfect.

Note:I have waited for a number of hours before testing each time to make sure the updates/settings have fully propagated

So what have I missed.. Any suggestions are very welcome

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure CDN PM here.
The 'Custom Origin' is a known portal bug, which does not affect the underlying settings, and will be fixed soon.

I would need more information from you to troubleshoot this.

Could you email me your CDN and origin endpoint, and a screenshot of your settings within the Azure portal for CDN and your web app? For example and the custom domain setup, which CDN profile type, etc.

My email is rli@microsoft.com

Comment: Hi, I returned to this a day later and it was working - miraculously. So it must have just taken longer than a couple of hours to update.

good to know about the Custom Origin anomaly.. so I will mark as answer

Thanks